# Hyphenation penalty

Tags: hyphenation, discretionary

Say I have done `\hyphenation{a-no-ma-ly}`. In the text, the word is broken ano-maly. This is (etymologically) displeasing, but may be better than the spacing that would result from barring it. Can I do something in the text to penalize this break? I tried `… ano\penalty100maly`, but that just produced a break with no hyphen.

PS: Is there no way to use `\penalty` (or something) with discretionary hyphens? Could one, for instance, redefine `\-` to work like this: `a\-1no\-2ma\-1ly`?

Comment: Are you trying to impose higher penalties for some hyphenation break points and lower penalties for others?

Comment: Yes. (In this case, I would say both alternatives, though bad, are better than ano-maly.)

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a way to apply different penalties to hyphenation points in a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169405/is-there-a-way-to-apply-different-penalties-to-hyphenation-points-in-a-word)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not in `\hyphenation`, this is a well known limitation of tex. It most often comes up for languages with lots of compound words where it would be good (but not possible) to prefer breaking between the compounds.

Also with the default settings of `\lefthyphenmin` and `\righthyphenmin` for English TeX will not use `a-nomaly` or `anoma-ly` so `\hyphenation{a-no-ma-ly}` is the same as `\hyphenation{ano-maly}`.

Within the text, in a given instance you can of course manually break anywhere

For example:

Forced break:

```
... an-\linebreak
omaly ...
```

or explicit discretionary:

```
... an\-omaly
```

The precedence for hyphenation selection is (1) explicit discretionaries within the word in text; (2) a pattern specified in the `\hyphenation` list (which can be limited to a particular language); (3) the specified patterns for the current language.

Comment: Can it not be done manually for a single occurrence either?

Comment: (My impression is that `a\-no\-ma\-ly` would break at the first discretionary that does not produce a badness of 10000 (?))

Comment: @Lawrence yes, the initial text just discussed automatic hyphenation, but the answer now clarifies (I hope) that you can break within the text. `a\-no\-ma\-ly` could break at any of those (not necessarily the first, whichever leads to the lowest overall badness for the paragraph)

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I have the feeling I have seen earlier that manual discretionaries produce other results than automatic `\hyphenation{}`, so I concluded they take the first acceptable; but maybe it was something else.

Comment: the precedence for hyphenation selection is (1) explicit discretionaries within the word in text; (2) a pattern specified in the `\hyphenation` list (which can be limited to a particular language); (3) the specified patterns for the current language. (@DavidCarlisle -- why don't you add this to your answer.)

Comment: but @barbarabeeton you have edit rights and you are so good at editing:-)

Comment: ah, but i wanted to make sure you didn't object before i did so.  (i was taught at a young age to be polite.)

Comment: Are their packages that allow to penitentials syllable-hypenation and therefore (at least try to) break the a word between its compounds (ie. a noun that consists of compounded nouns like houseboat or football)? Without prioritising the breaking of compounded nouns between the nouns, instead of hyphenating between "random" syllables, packages like `ragged2e` seem to be rather useless, at least for languages that use a lot of (long) compound words (like "Rindfleischetikettierungsueberwachungsaufgabenuebertragungsgesetz" ;)) Will this issue be addressed in LaTeX 3 or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @harryhaller tex has no way to specify priorities for different hyphenation points within a word (unless the compound word joins are explictly marked). LaTeX (3 or otherwise) can not address a feature that is not supported in the underlying engine. It is possible in theory to do this in luatex in that there is a lua callback so if you write a hyphenation algorithm you can plug it in. i have seen some experiments in that direction but nothing generally usable as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

In LuaTEX you can use `\hyphenpenalty` to give the undesirable hyphenation a harsher penalty than the
default, which is 50.

```
\newcommand\hyphenif[1]{{\hyphenpenalty#1\-}}

{\let\\\hyphenif
  a\-no\\{80}ma\\{60}ly}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Sadly this doesn't work (except in LuaTeX) since TeX will always use the value of `\hyphenpenalty` which is active at the end of the paragraph and not the value which is active when the `\-` is encountered.